# how to apply aes(size=...) to some sets of data (point) range, for each range seperatly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, geom, geom-point

I have some range of data which I used `aes(color=data_range)`. Now I want to change size in each range when I plot. when I use `aes(size=...)`, all data in all ranges change by size. but how to change size for each specific range? I mean, in each range points grow by their value. But independent of other ranges of data.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think is to add each range in a specific `geom_point()` and add all of them together. Each `geom_point()` will have an argument `aes(size)`.